# how to change "stopped message" in android

Tags: android

When I am programming an android application, sometimes the app closes, and the error message "com.example.activity has been stopped" message is being shown. I want the app to write different than the package name, like "Sorry for unexpected error". How can I manage this?

Comment: This error, at the first place should be avoided.

Comment: You simply produced some critical bug - check LogCat to identify it and fix.

Answer (score 2):

When that dialog is shown, your application has already stopped so there's no way to change that from your code.

Instead, fix the bugs in your code so that it does not crash in the first place.

Then you can add your own runtime error indications. For example, a toast or an alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) with your own [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

Any uncaught Java exception will go to your exception handler then where you, theoretically, could show your own message. I haven't tried it though.